# How to get immediate parent by Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

**html:**

```
<span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"><input class="spinner1 ui-spinner-input" id="q1" name="value" value="1" min="1" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuenow="2" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton"><a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n">▲</span></span></a><a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">▼</span></span></a></span>
```

**jquery:**

```
$('.ui-spinner-button').click(function() {
    //
});
```

I want to get the id and value of aria-valuenow

```
<input class="spinner1 ui-spinner-input" id="q1" name="value" value="1" min="1" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuenow="2" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton">
```

when I click on `.ui-spinner-button`

How can I do this. I googled  for couple of day but no luck.

Comment: You can use .parent() to get the parent.

Comment: `$(this).prev().attr('aria-valuenow') or $(this).siblings('.spinner1').attr('aria-valuenow')`

Comment: use `$(this).prev('.ui-spinner-input').attr('aria-valuenow')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `parent` here, you need the `prev` sibling. To get the previous input use [`siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selector.

See comments in the code below:

```js
$('.ui-spinner-button').click(function() {

  // Get the spinner input jquery object
  var $input = $(this).siblings('.ui-spinner-input');


  // Get attribute values
  var id = $input.attr('id'),
    valueNow = $input.attr('aria-valuenow');
  alert(id + ' >>> ' + valueNow);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="ui-spinner ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
  <input class="spinner1 ui-spinner-input" id="q1" name="value" value="1" min="1" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuenow="2" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton">
<a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-up ui-corner-tr ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-n">▲</span></span>
</a><a class="ui-spinner-button ui-spinner-down ui-corner-br ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-button-text-only" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="false"><span class="ui-button-text"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s">▼</span></span></a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need `parentNode` or `$.parent()`. Use `$(element).parent()` to get the immediate parent. In your case:

```
$('.ui-spinner-button').click(function(){
  $(this).parent(); // gives you the immediate parent as a jQuery object.
  $(this).attr("aria-valuenow"); // gives aria-valuenow.
  $(this).attr("id"); // gives you the ID
  this.id; // gives you the ID
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the JQuery code that worked for me:

```
$('.ui-spinner-button').click(function () {
    var elem = $(this).parent().find("input");
    alert("id: "+ elem.attr("id")+ ", aria-valuenow: "+ elem.attr("aria-valuenow")));
});
```

[Here is a JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sbpr6gju/)